# javascript - click is not a function error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am creating a confirmation box where users will click delete and it will ask then if they are sure or not.

this is the html

```
    <a href="" class="delete"  >Delete</a>
```

this is the JS handler

```
        (function($){
              var deleteBox = '<span class="deleteBox"><p>Are you sure you want to delete?</p><span class="cancel">Cancel</span><span class="confirm">Yes</span></span>';
              $(document).on('click', '#deleteproduct', (function(){
                $(this).append(deleteBox);
              }).click(function(){
                if(!$(this).hasClass('selected')){
                  $(this).addClass('selected');
                  var owner = $(this);

                  $(this).find('.cancel').unbind('click').bind('click',function(){
                    owner.removeClass('selected');
                    return false;
                  })

                  $(this).find('.confirm').unbind('click').bind('click',function(){
                    $(this).parent().addClass('loading');
                    var parent = $(this).parent();

                    //ajax to delete

                    setTimeout(function(){ //On success
                      parent.addClass('deleted');
                      setTimeout(function(){
                        owner.fadeOut(600);

                        //remove item deleted

                        setTimeout(function(){
                          owner.find('.deleted').removeClass('loading').removeClass('deleted');
                          owner.removeClass('selected');
                          owner.show();
                        },1000) 
                      },1000)
                    },1000)

                    return false;
                  })
                }   
                return false;
              }));
      })(jQuery);
```

this is the error its showing

```
   TypeError: (intermediate value).click is not a function at this line   ......  }).click(function(){
```

how can I fix this error?

Comment: Why do you use unbind('click')? you can simply use .onclick = function();

Comment: @artgb maybe because jQuery doesn't have an `onclick` property?

Comment: any explanation why this was downvoted?

Comment: @Ola, Kindly upvote the answer you think helps you the most in your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you try to add a `click` handler to the result of `.on()`, which, apparently is not supported. If you want to add the handler to `deleteBox`, then you need

```
deleteBox.click(function() {/*Do something*/});
```

EDIT:

This is how the idea can be applied:

```
  (function($){
                  var deleteBox = '<span class="deleteBox"><p>Are you sure you want to delete?</p><span class="cancel">Cancel</span><span class="confirm">Yes</span></span>';
                  $(document).on('click', '#deleteproduct', (function(){
                    $(this).append(deleteBox);
                  }));
                  $(deleteBox).click(function(){
                    if(!$(this).hasClass('selected')){
                      $(this).addClass('selected');
                      var owner = $(this);

                      $(this).find('.cancel').unbind('click').bind('click',function(){
                        owner.removeClass('selected');
                        return false;
                      })

                      $(this).find('.confirm').unbind('click').bind('click',function(){
                        $(this).parent().addClass('loading');
                        var parent = $(this).parent();

                        //ajax to delete

                        setTimeout(function(){ //On success
                          parent.addClass('deleted');
                          setTimeout(function(){
                            owner.fadeOut(600);

                            //remove item deleted

                            setTimeout(function(){
                              owner.find('.deleted').removeClass('loading').removeClass('deleted');
                              owner.removeClass('selected');
                              owner.show();
                            },1000) 
                          },1000)
                        },1000)

                        return false;
                      })
                    }   
                    return false;
                  });
          })(jQuery);
```

Comment: so what should i delete to add that? how should I implement that in the code

Comment: @Ola if you cannot apply this idea for your code, then I would like to kindly ask you to create a JSFiddle where I will solve this problem for you.

Comment: @Ola thank you, I have added jQuery as a resource to it: https://jsfiddle.net/wvnjvd2u/1/

Comment: @Ola I have edited my answer, for some reason the script only works in the Fiddle if you click on the Run button. But it works

Answer (score 4):

You are calling `.click` on `(function(){})`, but the function-declaration in `$(document).on('click', '#deleteproduct', (function(){...})` doesn't return anything with a function click. Instead, you could make something like the following, which adds the html when `Delete product` is clicked and uses jQuery to add click-events to the html.

```js
var deleteBox = '<span class="deleteBox"><p>Are you sure you want to delete?</p><span class="cancel">Cancel</span> <span class="confirm">Yes</span></span>';

$('#deleteproduct').click(function() {
  var $result = $('#result');
  var $popup = $('#popup');
  $result.text("");
  $popup.append(deleteBox);
  $popup.find('.cancel').click(function () {
    $popup.html("");
    $result.text("Cancelled");
  });
  $popup.find('.confirm').click(function () {
    $popup.html("");
    $result.text("Confirmed");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="deleteproduct">Delete product</button>
<div id="popup"></div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this

```
<a href="" onclick="popup()" class="delete"  >Delete</a>
```

and your js code will be like

```
function popup(){
   //do your stuff here

}
```